# Call C# Method with JS

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to create a login page that changes dynamically based on user attributes, specifically a username and role that is logged into a cookie. The login works fine; however, because I am using a really round-about way of calling C# functions, when my javascript method is called that contains the inline C# call, it skips all other lines of code in that method and goes right for the C# function.

I have read that a better way of going about this is the use of Webmethods and JQuery Ajax, however, I am unable to declare webmethods in my C# file.

My front end looks like the following

**Login.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>PAM testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Site.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/JScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="banner">PAM Testing Tool</div>
    <div id="content">
        <form id="form1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 25%; text-align: center; height: 41px; width: 292px;">
            <%--Login ASP Object--%>
            <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" onclick="process()"></asp:Login>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" style="text-align: center" ValidationGroup="Login1" />
        </form>

        <%--TEST AREA--%>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function logCookie(){
                document.cookie = "user=" + document.getElementById("Login1_UserName").value;// this is the id of username input field once displayed in the browser
            }

            function testFunction() {
                <%=Login1_Authenticate() %>;
            }

            function process(){
                logCookie();
                testFunction();
            }

        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My C# code looks like this

**Login.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.EnterpriseServices;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int status;
    int role;
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlDataReader reader;


    protected string Login1_Authenticate()
    {

        // create an open connection
        conn =
            new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;"
            + "Initial Catalog=xxx;"
            + "User ID=xxx;Password=xxx");

        conn.Open();

        //string userName;
        //userName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());


        // create a SqlCommand object for this connection
        command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.SP_CA_CHECK_USER @USER_ID = '"+Login1.UserName+"', @PASSWORD = '"+Login1.Password+"'";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // execute the command that returns a SqlDataReader
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // display the results
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        status = reader.GetInt32(0);
        }

        // close first reader
        reader.Close();

        //----------
        existTest();
        return "the login process is finished";

    }


    public static string GetData(int userid)
    {
        /*You can do database operations here if required*/
        return "my userid is" + userid.ToString();
    }

    public string existTest()
    {
        if (status == 0)
        {
            //login
            Session["userID"] = Login1.UserName;



            command.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.SP_CA_RETURN_USER_ROLE @USER_ID = '" + Login1.UserName + "'";
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                role = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }

            Session["roleID"] = role;

            if (Session["userID"] != null)
            {
                string userID = (string)(Session["userID"]);
                //string roleID = (string)(Session["roleID"]);
            }
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            //wrong username/password
        }



        // close the connection
        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
        return "process complete";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't call serverside code from the javascript that way. That code simply renders the return value of your method into the HTML. Normally you should have a button inside your form that will do postback to the server. Or instead of using clientside onclick in your asp:Login control, take a look at the OnLoggingIn server side event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your method as a web-service (web-api is good) then call it using jS ajax, here's an example i use with web-api and JS (this is posting data, use get if you have nothing to post)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "//localhost:38093/api/Acc/",  //method Name 
    data: JSON.stringify({ someVar: 'someValue', someOtherVar: 'someOtherValue'}),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: someFunction(), // callback above
    error: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.responsetext);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to convert my C# function into a a web api? When looking at online references, all of them suggest using the MVC4 framework and essentially setting up an entirely new project. Thank you

Comment: Hi, really web-api can be straightForward, create a Web-api project, right click controllers add new controller, name this TestController

Comment: using the options web api controller with read write options, look in the controller you'll see a bunch of methods you'll see api/Test, that's your URL , to call post use the example above just pass a single arg , you may need to decorate your controller with [HttpPost]... add something in the method like var x=value , put a breakpoint on this call it from JS and the rest is pretty much standard c# from there on, be aware of CORS (cross origin resource sharing)...ran out of space..