# Converting Serverside C# to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

After posting on how to get server side information to JS (on client side) [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685973/call-c-sharp-method-with-js/24686825#24686825), I was advised to create my server side logic into a Web Api in order to expose data via HTTP through a JQuery AJAX call. After looking through a lot of documentation, and even a [tutorial series online hosted by Microsoft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjwfcOKC_nQ), I found little to no good instruction. Previously, I was calling my serverside methods through inline C# calls in my js script, but learned that because C# is precompiled, it simply just "fills in" the values returned by the C# functions.

Just for a reference as to how I am improperly calling my C# methods.

This is my front end: **Login.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>PAM testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Site.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/JScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="banner">PAM Testing Tool</div>
    <div id="content">
        <form id="form1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 25%; text-align: center; height: 41px; width: 292px;">
            <%--Login ASP Object--%>
            <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" onclick="process()"></asp:Login>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" style="text-align: center" ValidationGroup="Login1" />
        </form>

        <%--TEST AREA--%>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function logCookie(){
                document.cookie = "user=" + document.getElementById("Login1_UserName").value;// this is the id of username input field once displayed in the browser
            }

            function testFunction() {
                <%=Login1_Authenticate() %>;
            }

            function process(){
                logCookie();
                testFunction();
            }

        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My C# code looks like this

**Login.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.EnterpriseServices;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int status;
    int role;
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlDataReader reader;


    protected string Login1_Authenticate()
    {

        // create an open connection
        conn =
            new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;"
            + "Initial Catalog=xxx;"
            + "User ID=xxx;Password=xxx");

        conn.Open();

        //string userName;
        //userName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());


        // create a SqlCommand object for this connection
        command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.SP_CA_CHECK_USER @USER_ID = '"+Login1.UserName+"', @PASSWORD = '"+Login1.Password+"'";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // execute the command that returns a SqlDataReader
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // display the results
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        status = reader.GetInt32(0);
        }

        // close first reader
        reader.Close();

        //----------
        existTest();
        return "the login process is finished";

    }


    public static string GetData(int userid)
    {
        /*You can do database operations here if required*/
        return "my userid is" + userid.ToString();
    }

    public string existTest()
    {
        if (status == 0)
        {
            //login
            Session["userID"] = Login1.UserName;



            command.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.SP_CA_RETURN_USER_ROLE @USER_ID = '" + Login1.UserName + "'";
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                role = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }

            Session["roleID"] = role;

            if (Session["userID"] != null)
            {
                string userID = (string)(Session["userID"]);
                //string roleID = (string)(Session["roleID"]);
            }
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            //wrong username/password
        }



        // close the connection
        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
        return "process complete";
    }
}
```

How can I convert my C# into Web api's? I would very much appreciate it if any answers could link me to good documentation or tutorials.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Side note: please make sure to check [SQL injection on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) for education and [bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) for entertainment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this into Web API would require creating a new Web API project, setting up your appropriate controllers, and moving Form Control to parameters to pass into the Controller methods.  Please visit this tutorial for more information on getting started with ASP.NET Web MVC:  [Getting Started With ASP-NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

**Please Note:**  Executing dynamic SQL the way you are doing in the above code leaves your application open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks! Please consider using parameterized SQL instead.